# Not able to install php memcache

Tags: memcached, homebrew

When I run `brew install php56-memcache` I get the following error.

```
checking whether to enable memcache session handler support... yes
checking for the location of ZLIB... no
checking for the location of zlib... configure: error: memcache support
requires ZLIB. Use --with-zlib-dir=<DIR> to specify prefix where ZLIB 
include and library are located
```

I have zlib in `brew list`.

```
autoconf    jpeg        memcached   php56       ruby-build
freetype    libevent    mhash       php56-igbinary  unixodbc
gettext     libmemcached    mysql       php56-memcached vim
git     libpng      node        pkg-config  zlib
icu4c       mcrypt      openssl     rbenv
```

I tried `bbrew install php56-memcache --with-zlib-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/zlib/1.2.8' but it gives the same error.

I tried a manual way, `./configure`, `make`, `make install`, but the result is the same.

How can I install memcache?

Answer (score 0):

I run the followings and it is installed.

```
brew link --force zlib
brew install php56-memcache
```

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me [[#1637]](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/1637), just run

```
xcode-select --install
brew install php{xx}-memcache
```